# C++ pointer to const pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, constants

I'm still confusing where to place `const` in pointers with more than one indirection. Can someone clarify?

E.g. right now I need a pointer to const pointer, meaning such a variable `int **ppTargets` that I can assign `int *pTargets` variable to it, like:

```
int foo(int **ppTargets) {
    int *pTargets = /* calculate here */;
    *ppTargets = pTargets;
    return 37; // just e.g.
}
```

The above code lacks `const`. So in `foo` I want `pTargets` to point to constant memory and be unassignable after initialization (so that one cannot write e.g. `pTargets++`), that would be `int const *const pTargets = /* assigned once */`. Next I want to declare `ppTargets` that `ppTargets` itself can be assigned, but then `*ppTargets` can only be read.

In the other words, in the *caller* code I want:

```
int const* pTargets;
foo(&pTargets);
```

I tried to declare `foo` as follows, but get an error `you cannot assign to a variable that is const`:

```
int foo(int *const *const ppTargets)
```

Comment: use `typedef` to build up from your simple types to the ones you actually want to use

Comment: [Clockwise/Spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: You're contradicting yourself: `So I want pTargets to point to constant memory and be const itself, that would be int const *const pTargets` ... then `In the other words, in the calling code I want: int const* pTargets;` So, which is it? Is `pTargets` supposed to be const or not?

Comment: @eerorika, in the other words, I want to forbid assignment to `pTargets` and `**pTargets`, but not `*pTargets`. I don't see a contradiction yet, let me think what could be misunderstood...

Comment: @SergeRogatch `I want to forbid assignment to pTargets` contradicts with `int const* pTargets` because `int const*` can be assigned.

Comment: @eerorika, now I see the confusion: that's different `pTargets` between caller and callee code.

Comment: this is C++ code, not C.  (They are two different languages) Strongly suggest removing the 'c' tag

Comment: @user3629249, I thought this is both C and C++ code. Could you elaborate what makes it C++ only?

Answer (score 5):

I always read C/C++ definitions from the right-most variable name leftwards.

So:

- `const char *p;`

  `p` is a pointer to a `char` that is `const`

  So `p` can be modified, but `*p` can’t.
- `const char * * const p = &a;`

  `p` is a `const` pointer to a pointer to a `char` that is `const`.

  So `p` cannot be modified (hence I initialised it); `*p` can; but `**p` can’t.

[EDIT - added arrays for completeness]

- `const char * * const p[4] = { &a, &b, &c, &d };`

  `p` is a 4-element array of `const` pointers to...

Comment: This. So the OP wants `int foo(const int ** const ppTargets)` (or `int foo(int const ** const ppTargets)`, which is the same thing).

Comment: OTOH, toplevel `const` in parameters is effectively meaningless for copyable types.

Comment: @TonyK no, OP said *"that `ppTargets` itself can be assigned"*. You cannot assign a `const int ** const`. And furthermore, the address of `int const *const` has a different type.

Comment: @eerorika: yes, reading the question again, you are right. But the OP contradicts himself, I think. So I will bow out of this one.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is `int const * const * ppTarget`. No, wait, you're looking for `int const ** const ppTarget`. No no, it's `int * const * const * ppTarget`.

Chances are one of them is correct (I'm betting the first one). However, you don't want people reading your code to guess what it is you mean. It's just too confusing. C++ can do that to you.

What you should do, is use `typedef`s to make sure people who read the code understand what you want.

```
typedef const int *CINT_PTR;
CINT_PTR pTarget = ....;
CINT_PTR *ppTarget = &pTarget;
```

Comment: The second one is correct, as John Burger explains.

Comment: That just makes my point stronger. It took three answers from people with 5-digit Stack Overflow reputation (two of them close to 100,000) to get this right. Don't write code that can only be understood by a group of experts after some debate.

Answer (score 1):

Since `pTargets` is a `const int *`, its address is a `const int **`, which is the type you want for the function parameter:

```
int foo(const int **ppTargets)
{
    int *pTargets = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
    pTargets[0] = 1;
    pTargets[1] = 2;
    pTargets[2] = 3;
    pTargets[3] = 4;
    *ppTargets = pTargets;
    return 37;
}

int main()
{
    int const *pTargets;
    foo(&pTargets);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

If the variable to set is defined as `int const * const pTargets;`, the only way to set it is when it is initialized.  You can then do this instead:

```
const int *foo2()
{
    int *pTargets = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
    pTargets[0] = 1;
    pTargets[1] = 2;
    pTargets[2] = 3;
    pTargets[3] = 4;
    return pTargets;
}

int main()
{
    int const * const pTargets = foo2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now how to avoid `ppTargets++` in the code of `foo`? Meaning that the variable itself is also `const`.

Comment: @SergeRogatch `ppTargets` is a local variable to `foo`, so if you change it then it isn't reflected in the calling function.

Comment: Calling this `foo` won't work if *"`pTargets` [points] to constant memory **and [is] const itself**"* like Serge states in the question. Your `pTargets` is non-const.

Comment: Why is `pTargets` declared as `int const *`and not `const int *` in main, then?

Comment: @zmbq Those are equivalent.

Comment: Well, I used to know that I guess, but this post has made me question everything I know about C++ const pointers. I also regret complaining there are no const references in C#.

Answer (score 1):

> So I want `pTargets` to point to constant memory and be `const` itself,
>   that would be `int const *const pTargets = /* assigned once */`. Next I
>   want to declare `ppTargets` that `ppTargets` itself can be assigned, but
>   then `*ppTargets` can only be read.

Unfortunately, that does not make sense.  Your example code assigns to `*ppTargets`, as indeed appears to be the primary objective of function `foo()`.  If `*ppTargets` can be assigned once, then it can be assigned again.

It is unclear why you want `foo()`'s local `pTargets` to be `const`, as opposed to just not modifying it, but you may assign a `const` value to an object of the corresponding non-`const`-qualifed type.  Thus, what you're actually looking for might be

```
int foo(int const **ppTargets) {
    int const * const pTargets = /* calculate here */;
    *ppTargets = pTargets;
    return 37; // just e.g.
}
```

And that seems to be consistent with your intended usage:

> In the other words, in the calling code I want:
>
> ```
> int const* pTargets;
> foo(&pTargets);
> ```

For any type `T`, the type of a pointer to a `T` can be spelled `T *`.  In particular, the type of this `&pTargets` is `int const **` (look familiar?), and that's the appropriate type for a function parameter through which the function should be able to set the value of the caller's `pTargets`.

And again, calling `foo()` to have it to set the value of the caller's `pTargets` seems to be exactly the point.  If `foo()` were supposed to be prevented from doing that, then the ideal approach would be to pass `pTargets` itself (by value), instead of passing its address and wrangling `const` qualifiers.

Comment: This won't compile since you can't assign to `*ppTargets`

Comment: Yes, @dbush.  I let myself be thrown off by the first part of the OP's request, which is for something that cannot actually work.  I have substantially rewritten this answer to address the problem with the OP's request and present something that *does* work.  I'm sure you won't be surprised that the function signature that works is what you presented, too.

Answer (score 0):

> So I want pTargets to point to constant memory and be const itself
>
> Next I want to declare ppTargets that ppTargets itself can be assigned, but then *ppTargets can only be read.

For clarity, let `int const *` be `Ptr` and let `int const * const` (i.e. `Ptr const`) be `CPtr`.

Just like you correctly wrote `int const *const pTargets` (i.e. `CPtr`) when you wanted a const pointer to const int, so too when you want a non-const pointer to const pointer to const int (i.e. the type of `&pTargets` i.e. `CPtr*`), you need `int const *const * ppTargets`. Note that a `Ptr*` will implicitly convert to `CPtr*`.

Your attempted `int *const *const ppTargets` would be a const pointer to const pointer to non-const int. Since the type is a const pointer, it cannot be assigned which contradicts with your requirement.

---

More generally, a simple rule of thumb is to read C pointer type declarations from right to left, and constness applies to the left of the keyword (except when it is the leftmost token in which case it applies to the right).

---

Now that we've found a type that meets your stated requirements, let me bring your attention to your implementation of `foo` which does `*ppTargets = pTargets`. This contradicts with the requirement of *"`*ppTargets` can only be read*".

Answer (score 0):

After the inputs from the others, especially the [Clockwise/Spiral](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) rule by @Mahesh , as well as some debate, I understood how to read and write such things easily.

We should look at what can and what cannot be modified. So consider the declaration without `const`s: `int **ppTargets`. We want that `ppTargets` cannot be modified itself, while `*pTargets` can be modified, while `**pTargets` cannot be modified.

Then, apply these observations right to left:
`int const * * const ppTargets`.

The rightmost `const` says that `ppTargets++` is not possible.

Then absence of `const` in the middle says that `(*ppTargets)=pTargets` is possible.

Then another, leftmost `const` says that `(**ppTargets)++` is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The basic formalization for indirection is in my view

```
(read-only|read-write) <memory zone> * (read-only|read-write) <pointer>
```

where `<pointer>` is itself a memory zone.
For double indirection, the expression becomes

```
(read-only|read-write) <memory zone> * (read-only|read-write) <memory zone/pointer-level2> * (read-only|read-write) <pointer-level1>
```

What makes things more difficult to understand is the possibility of placing qualifiers (eg. `read-only`) before OR after `<memory zone>` on the left size of `*` symbol. On the right side of `*` symbol, the qualifier(s) can be placed only before `<pointer>`.

In C++ `read-only` means **const** and `read-write` is the implicit qualifier.

Thus we can have:

- `char* p` read-write pointer to read-write `char` memory zone
- `const char* p` read-write pointer to **read-only** `char` memory zone
- `char* const p` **read-only** pointer to read-write `char` memory zone
- `const char* const p` **read-only** pointer to **read-only** `char` memory zone

Then we can move `const` after the basic type resulting equivalent declarations:

- `char const* p` read-write pointer to **read-only** `char` memory zone
- `char const* const p` **read-only** pointer to **read-only** `char` memory zone

Pointer conversion is allowed having equal qualifier or less restrictive qualifier in source pointer for each level of indirection comparing to destination pointer.

As result the following cases are valid:

```
int foo(const int* const* const p);

{// equal leftmost qualifier
const int* p = nullptr;

const int** p1 = &p; // 2nd and 3rd qualifiers are less restrictive
foo(p1);

const int* const* p2 = &p; // 2nd qualifier is equal, 3rd one (implicit read-write) is less restrictive
foo(p2);

const int* const* const p3 = &p; // 2nd and 3rd qualifiers are equal
foo(p3);
}

{// less restrictive leftmost qualifier of p
int* p = nullptr;

int** p1 = &p; // 2nd and 3rd qualifiers are less restrictive
foo(p1); 

int* const* p2 = &p; // 2nd qualifier is equal, 3rd one (implicit read-write) is less restrictive
foo(p2);

int* const* const p3 = &p; // 2nd and 3rd qualifiers are equal
foo(p3);
}
```

In your case the leftmost qualifier of the pointer passed as argument (`&pTargets`) is not equal or less restrictive than the leftmost qualifier of the pointer from `foo` function.